# Doesn't show the image on imageview in horizontal listview

Tags: android, android-imageview, baseadapter, android-gallery

I tried to implement the Horizontal ListView. In this activity, I have one ImageView and one Horizontal ListView. If I select any image from this horizontal ListView, that image will show above the Horizontal ListView. By default, the first image is showing on that ImageView. Here the image is not showing on ImageView:

```
String  Imagefile ="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Screenshot_2014-10-07-11-52-52-1412678971.png";
selectedImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
imageLoader=new ImageLoader(DetailPage.this.getApplicationContext());
imageLoader.DisplayImage(Imagefile, selectedImage);
```

Now the image is showing well on ImageView. But if I tried to set dynamic image, the image is not showing on the ImageView.

```
 GalleryImageAdapter adapter = new GalleryImageAdapter(DetailPage.this, categories);
 gallery.setAdapter(adapter);
 String  Imagefile =categories[0].toString();
 selectedImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
 //imageLoader=new ImageLoader(DetailPage.this.getApplicationContext());
 //imageLoader.DisplayImage(Imagefile, selectedImage);
 gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
 System.out.println("Selected-Image"+" "+categories[position].toString());
  //imageLoader=new ImageLoader(DetailImage.this.getApplicationContext());
  // imageLoader.DisplayImage(categories[position].toString(), selectedImage);

            }
        });  
        }
      class GalleryImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
     {
     private final Context context;
      private final String[] categories;
      public ImageLoader imageLoader; 
      public GalleryImageAdapter(Context context, String[] categories) {
        super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, categories);
        this.context = context;
        this.categories = categories;
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(context.getApplicationContext());
      }

      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View i = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) i.findViewById(R.id.icon);
       // imageLoader=new ImageLoader(context.getApplicationContext());
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(categories[position], imageView);
        System.out.println("Image"+" "+categories[position]);
        return i;
    }
   }
```

But I am getting the url on logcat:

```
10-07 16:46:35.559: I/System.out(1105): default-Image "http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Screenshot_2014-10-07-11-52-52-1412678971.png"
10-07 17:22:50.009: I/System.out(3607): Image http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Screenshot_2014-10-07-11-52-52-1412678971.png
```

What is wrong in my code ?

**EDIT:**

Yes, I have changed my code like :

```
      GalleryImageAdapter adapter = new GalleryImageAdapter(DetailImage.this, R.layout.rowlayout,categories);

      class GalleryImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
      {
      private final Context context;
      private final String[] categories;
      public ImageLoader imageLoader;
      private int resourceId; 
      public GalleryImageAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,String[] categories) {
        super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, categories);
        this.context = context;
        this.resourceId = resourceId;
        this.categories = categories;
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(context.getApplicationContext());
      }

      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View i = inflater.inflate(resourceId, parent, false);
```

But still now doesn't showing the image on ImageView. Please verify it.

**EDIT:**

I need exact output with dynamic data like below tutorial :

http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/07/android-gallery-view-example.html

Comment: check your link not working http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Screenshot_2014-10-07-11-52-52-1412678971.png

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar That link is sample one only..I have used valid url...We are restrict our url on public.that's why i have posted with sample url.

Comment: use this image url http://techbeasts.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Android1.jpg

Comment: @KrishnaVeni : u should load images inside `GalleryImageAdapter`

Comment: What do you mean by horizontal listview? @KrishnaVeni

Comment: and which imageloader library did you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code modified which is working fine for me Since i dont know which imageloader you have used i used universal image loader and with a simple list view.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
ImageView selectedImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView gallery;
    gallery = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_horiz);
    final String[] categories;
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
            getApplicationContext()).build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
    categories = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.images);
    GalleryImageAdapter adapter = new GalleryImageAdapter(
            getApplicationContext(), getResources().getStringArray(
                    R.array.images));
    gallery.setAdapter(adapter);        
    selectedImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            System.out.println("Selected-Image" + " "
                    + categories[position].toString());
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(
                    categories[position].toString(), selectedImage);

        }
    });
}
```

}

Class for adapter:

```
class GalleryImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Context context;
private final String[] categories;
public ImageLoader imageLoader;

public GalleryImageAdapter(Context context, String[] categories) {
    super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, categories);
    this.context = context;
    this.categories = categories;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);     
    View i = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
    ImageView imginlist = (ImageView) i.findViewById(R.id.iv_inlist);
    TextView text = (TextView) i.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(categories[position], imginlist);
    System.out.println("Image" + " " + categories[position]);
    return i;
}
```

}

**Note:** This only changes the image at the top when you click on the listview image(the image inside the listview) if you want to change the image when the image itself viewed from the listview just declare a static method inside the activity and call it from the adapter getview.
 **PS** PM me if u need the sample prjoect as Zip.

Comment: Yes it's working fine., if i have using the universal image loader library.Thanks :)

Comment: You Welcome @KrishnaVeni :) (y)

Answer (score 1):

create `ImageLoader's` object inside constructor not in `getView(...)`

```
public GalleryImageAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, String[] categories) {
  super(context, resourceId, categories);
  this.context = context;
  this.resourceId = resourceId;
  this.categories = categories;
  imageLoader=new ImageLoader(context.getApplicationContext());
}
```

comment out those lines inside `onItemClick`

In `Activity` where you creating object for `GalleryImageAdapter` pass layout as paramater like this

```
GalleryImageAdapter adapter = new GalleryImageAdapter(DetailPage.this, R.layout.rowlayout, categories);
```

In `getView(...)` instead of `R.layout.rowlayout` use `resourceId`.

**P.S :** [Public Constructors of ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)

Comment: yes i have changed like your logic..but image is not showing.

Comment: I have updated my code.but i didn't get the solution.

Answer (score 1):

okay this is what im thinking the problem is on your imageloader class..try this in your mainactivity or global activity... 
copy and paste this very code

```
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .cacheInMemory()
    .cacheOnDisc()
    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)     
    .build();
    // Load and display image
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(c)
    .defaultDisplayImageOptions(options)
    .build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

then in your array constructor remove and replace --(this is the old constructor-(yours))

```
public GalleryImageAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,String[] categories) {
    super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, categories);
    this.context = context;
    this.resourceId = resourceId;
    this.categories = categories;
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(context.getApplicationContext()); //remove this line
  }
```

now you have-(editted constructor)

```
public GalleryImageAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,String[] categories) {
    super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, categories);
    this.context = context;
    this.resourceId = resourceId;
    this.categories = categories;
  }
```

then come down to your getview and do this -(you can copy paste this to replace getview)

```
@Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View i = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) i.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(categories[position], imageView);
    System.out.println("Image"+" "+categories[position]);
    return i;
}
```

Note: If Display Options wasn't passed to ImageLoader.displayImage(...)method then default Display Options from configuration (ImageLoaderConfiguration.defaultDisplayImageOptions(...)) will be used.

let me know if it helps

Comment: well why didn't i got the 50 bounty reputaion? @Elltz? does she have to provide me manually? :D LOL

Comment: LOL...yeah she has to provide it manually, but the fact that she accepted your answer during the bounty period will make you gain the bounty reward after the grace period in 4 hours [more info about bounty jux btw](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) @Vigneshearan.m

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line

```
View i = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
```

to

```
View i = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have commented the line for creating the imageloader object and setting that image onto the selectedImage object.

```
gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        System.out.println("Selected-Image"+" "+categories[position].toString());
        // imageLoader=new ImageLoader(DetailImage.this.getApplicationContext());
        // imageLoader.DisplayImage(categories[position].toString(), selectedImage);
    }
});
```

change it to:

```
gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        System.out.println("Selected-Image"+" "+categories[position].toString());
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(DetailImage.this.getApplicationContext());
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(categories[position].toString(), selectedImage);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Volley's Network ImageView

You just need to follow this [tutorial](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2014/02/01/android-volley-tutorial/)